# USB Camera for Google Duo in Philips Android TV

Tags: android-tv, video-calling, video-conference

I have a Philips 49pus7503 Android TV. As you know, Google allows Duo calls on Android TV at late 2020. As I read in Google Duo in Android TV article from Google, it says that "Simply connect USB camera to TV, after that you can use this camera with microphone also.". I connect my old Logitech C270 camera, however Duo cannot find the camera. How can I do ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Philips 49pus7503 manual online](https://www.download.p4c.philips.com/files/5/55pus7503_12/55pus7503_12_dfu_eng.pdf) I don't see any mention of supporting a USB webcam.

And sadly, the [Android Compatibility Definition Document](https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd#7_7_usb) gives device manufacturers the option of not supporting:

> **7.5.3. External Camera**
>
> **MAY** include support for an external camera that is not necessarily always connected.